# Using instance variables in SQLite3 update?

Tags: python, sqlite, instance-variables

Ok so basically I'm trying to update an existing SQLite3 Database with instance variables (typ and lvl)

```
#Set variables
typ = 'Test'
lvl = 6

#Print Databse
print("\nHere's a listing of all the records in the table:\n")
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM fieldmap ORDER BY rowid"):
    print(row)

#Update Info
sql = """
UPDATE fieldmap
SET buildtype = typ, buildlevel = lvl
WHERE rowid = 11
"""

cursor.execute(sql)

#Print Databse
print("\nHere's a listing of all the records in the table:\n")
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM fieldmap ORDER BY rowid"):
    print(row)
```

As an Error I'm getting

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: typ
```

Now I basically know the problem is that my variable is inserted with the wrong syntax but I can not for the life of me find the correct one. It works with strings and ints just fine like this:

```
sql = """
UPDATE fieldmap
SET buildtype = 'house', buildlevel = 3
WHERE rowid = 11
"""
```

But as soon as I switch to the variables it throws the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not actually inserting the values of the variables `typ` and `lvl` into the query string. As written the query is trying to reference columns named `typ` and `lvl`, but these don't exist in the table.

Try writing is as a parameterised query:

```
sql = """
UPDATE fieldmap
SET buildtype = ?, buildlevel = ?
WHERE rowid = 11
"""

cursor.execute(sql, (typ, lvl))
```

The `?` acts as a placeholder in the query string which is replaced by the values in the tuple passed  to `execute()`. This is a secure way to construct the query and avoids SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think you should use ORM to manipulate with SQL database.

SQLAlchemy is your friend. I use that with SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL. It is fantastic.

That can make you get away from this syntax error since SQL does take commas and quotation marks as importance.

For hard coding, you may try this:

```
sql = """
UPDATE fieldmap
SET buildtype = '%s', buildlevel = 3
WHERE rowid = 11
"""  % (house)
```

This can solve your problem temporarily but not for the long run. ORM is your friend.

Hope this could be helpful!

Comment: **NEVER** use `%s` or `str.format` in SQL commands passed to your database. It is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @aim100k Yes we know. That's why we use ORM instead of hard coding. Yet people who care mostly about the injection would do their own SQL ORM other than using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @dotslash chill dude, I was just hinting at using `?` syntax provided by sqlite3. Also, if you are not narrow minded, search for `orm is an anti-pattern`, I think the new perspective has some merit to it